# How do I read an already declared char string that is a unicode character as a hexadecimal 2 digit value?

Tags: c, unicode, hex, byte

Given two strings, I have to read the hexadecimal 2 digit values of each of their unicode values. disregarding the ASCII characters.

```
char * str1 = "⍺";
char * str2 = "alpha is ⍺, beta is β and mu is µ";
```

I tried to print these values using:   `printf("<%02x>\n", str1);`, but it seems like the value is wrong (also did this with `(unsigned char)` and it didn't seem to work).

Output should be something like this

```
<e2>
<e8><a2><2e>
```

Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *str1 = "⍺";
char *str2 = "alpha is ⍺, beta is β and mu is µ";
char *str3 = "β";
char *str4 = "µ";

int main(){
    printf("<%x>\n", (unsigned char) * str1);
    printf("<%x>", (unsigned char) * str1);
    printf("<%x>", (unsigned char) * str3);
    printf("<%x>\n", (unsigned char) * str4);
}
```

Comment: The "char" type in C is a single byte. If your compiler is compiling those strings without an error, it's probably doing so using the UTF-8 encoding, so those Greek letters will be multi-byte sequences, not 2-digit hex values. And since when are "l" and "q" hex digits?

Comment: Have you tried `printf("<%02x>\n", (unsigned char)str1[0]);`? Your `printf("<%02x>\n", str1);` should generate a compiler warning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  What are your plans for dealing with adjacent characters with codes from U+0080 upwards?  For example, `"å¬€£Åºüÿ"` (or `"⍺βµ"`)?  Do you expect to output `><` between each pair of adjacent non-ASCII characters, or will you just print a string of hex inside a single set of angle brackets?  What have you tried?  What happened?  Why didn't you show us what you've tried as an MCVE — [MCVE]?

Comment: Lee Daniel Crocker, I was just trying to demonstrate the two digit idea.

Comment: I tried to use the method by Weather Vane but it still gives me a value of e2

Comment: That is for string one and it prints one value of 61 for string 2

Comment: You've still not shown the code you're using — so we can't really tell what you're doing wrong.  We know you're doing it wrong, but we can't guess which of many possible techniques you've used to do it wrong.

Comment: Okay I have updated it with the only way I can get different values for the unicode characters. I wanted to do this without having to declare separate chars. I wanted the two original strings and then to be able to read through them and print only the unicode characters hex values

Comment: So, you print the first byte of each string, and only the first byte.  The characters such as `"⍺βµ"` all require multiple bytes, so you'll need to print each byte in turn.  Hence my question about whether and how to insert `><` between separate UTF8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

This code goes through the bytes of a string, and identifies the 'ASCII' characters (Unicode U+0000 .. U+007F), and usually doesn't print them, and for the Unicode characters from U+0080 upwards, prints out a `<`, the series of pairs of hex digits representing the character, and eventually a `>` at the end, with `><` in the middle separating separate UTF8-encoded Unicode character.  If you pass in one or more arguments, it prints the 'ASCII' characters too, but as themselves, not in the hex encoding.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void dump_str(const char *s);

static bool print_ascii = false;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *strings[] =
    {
        "⍺",
        "alpha is ⍺, beta is β and mu is µ",
        "At -37ºC, the £ and the € fall apart",
        "å¬€£Åºüÿ",
        "⍺βµ",
    };
    enum { NUM_STRINGS = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]) };

    // Use argv - my compilation options don't allow unused parameters to a function
    if (argc > 1 && argv[argc] == NULL)
        print_ascii = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
        dump_str(strings[i]);
    return 0;
}

static void dump_str(const char *s)
{
    int c;
    bool printing_ascii = true;
    while ((c = (unsigned char)*s++) != '\0')
    {
        if (isascii(c))
        {
            if (!printing_ascii)
            {
                printing_ascii = true;
                putchar('>');
            }
            if (print_ascii)
                putchar(c);
        }
        else
        {
            if (printing_ascii)
            {
                printing_ascii = false;
                putchar('<');
            }
            else
            {
                if ((c & 0xC0) != 0x80)
                {
                    putchar('>');
                    putchar('<');
                }
            }
            printf("%2x", c);
        }
    }
    if (!printing_ascii)
        putchar('>');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

I called the program `utf8-97`; when run, it gave me:

```
$ ./utf8-97
<e28dba>
<e28dba><ceb2><c2b5>
<c2ba><c2a3><c2a0><e282ac>
<c3a5><c2ac><e282ac><c2a3><c385><c2ba><c3bc><c3bf>
<e28dba><ceb2><c2b5>
$ ./utf8-97 1
<e28dba>
alpha is <e28dba>, beta is <ceb2> and mu is <c2b5>
At -37<c2ba>C, the <c2a3><c2a0>and the <e282ac> fall apart
<c3a5><c2ac><e282ac><c2a3><c385><c2ba><c3bc><c3bf>
<e28dba><ceb2><c2b5>
$
```

The `<c2a0>` sequence is for a non-breaking space that I accidentally put/left in the code after the pound symbol £.  I'm not sure if you'll get that if you copy the code from the answer.